# Events not display in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

This is my firstday with fullcalendar, and i tried to load events in json format but the event is not loaded

i made a jsbin and simplified my snippet.
my html is a default:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <link href='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.4.0/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
        <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.4.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>

        <!-- the code from the JavaScript tab will go here -->

        <!-- the code from the CSS tab will go here -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my script is simply:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        events:'apps/data.php'
    })
})
```

My Data is only:

```
 [{title  : 'event1',start  : '2015-08-01'}]
```

i made a jsbin that [You can access by click here](http://jsbin.com/hihage/edit?html,js,output)

Any insight to see what went wrong ? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out it because unproper json data,
it supposed to :

```
[{"title"  : "event1","start"  : "2015-08-01"}]
```